# Multiple tab index for single usercontrol in c#

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control and this usercontrol is used in two different parts of a single aspx page. It used twice in the page, once on the page and the other on the pop-up of the page. I have given tab index for the controls in the usercontrol. When i press tab button in the page usercontrol, tab index works fine. But when i press tab button in the popup usercontrol, the tab index focusses to the page usercontrol.

Answer (score -1):

After opening popup, you should focus manually to the your prefer control and give proper tabindex to the controls on popup page/div/anything else.

Comment: The div contains the same usercontrol. so when i press tab, the focus moves to the first usercontrol.